# flags when running nodejs apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, bash

can someone explain the meaning of the following flags in the sample npm commands:

1. `node -r esm index.js`
2. `nodemon -x ts-node  ./src/index.ts`

So FYI, the `esm` module allows the use of `es6` modules in node. These are completely un-related commands that I have seen in some package.json, I was wondering what's the specific use of the `-r` and `-x` flags in these. Are these some bash flags or are these related to node somehow.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check this blog: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_resolver_algorithm.

As far as I know -r stands for experimental specifier resolution which value is `node` in your case.